# link to a bookmark from different page in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have to create couple of links to the bookmarks of a page, But the problem is it the links are in different page. How do i create a link pointing to a specific part of a page from another page?

I created the link with and added a bookmark like the one shown below

https://he.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteOffices/SitePages/test.aspx#test

but it always goes to the page not to the specific location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specific to SharePoint, but general HTML, regardless of the product that generates it.

The anchor setup may differ from IE to Chrome or Firefox, especially with older versions of IE. In general, try to use both the ID and the Name tags in the anchor, to serve all browser types.

On the page with the link use:

```
<a href="/path/library/page.aspx#anchor">link text</a>
```

On the page with the bookmark create this:

```
<a name="anchor" id="anchor">paragraph</a>
```

Comment: i did the same as advised <a href="/sites/SiteOffices/SitePages/test.aspx#anchor">link text</a>   and for the page with bookmark ;<a name="anchor" id="anchor"> KEO INTERNATIONAL CONSULTANTS</a></h4> with no luck though, it goes to the top of the page.

Comment: What browser and version are you using?

Comment: it started working after the restart of the browser.